# UIButton occasionally partially/not visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder

I have a view built with Interface Builder which has a grid of buttons (like so):
X X
X X

The bottom pair are the ones causing issues. Nothing happens programatically to the buttons at all (they aren't even connected to the code, they just call selectors). I've set the Button Image of both to two different images. Before setting the image for each, they both showed up fine as buttons, but as soon as I set the image, they're acting strange.

Sometimes (very rarely) they show up fine. Other times, the image is squashed to one side, filling less than half the button area. Most times they just don't appear at all. Each acts independently, so the behaviour of both buttons is never the same. They're set up with the custom button style (not round rect buttons). What I don't get is that the top pair of buttons are set up identically (in fact, they're copied and pasted) and they always show up fine. I've compared the properties of each and they're identical in that respect.

Comment: Is autolayout on? If so, try turning it off.

Comment: fixed it, thanks :). I'd already designed my interface for both iPhone 5 and 4(S)-, so resizing wasn't an issue for me.

Comment: @AlexBlundell how did u fix it? :)

Comment: Turned off Auto layout for the view in the storyboard